Access Issue to navigation2 Documentation Website. Is website off?
I am experiencing issues accessing the navigation2 documentation website at navigation.ros.org. When attempting to access the site, I receive a DNS error: "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN."
Steps Taken:

Checked URL for typos.
Tried accessing the website using multiple browsers and devices.
Cleared DNS cache on my system.
Used a VPN to access the site from a different geographical location (USA).
Attempted to use different networks and public DNS services.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. Could there be an ongoing issue with the website's DNS settings, or is the site currently undergoing maintenance? Any information or assistance in resolving this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for looking into this matter.


There is a new website at http://docs.nav2.org/, see the announcement on the ROS Discourse.
